# How can I make a dropdown menu appear outside of its parent div?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using [react-responsive-select][1] for a dropdown component within an interface. I have a table with various factors that a user can modify, including two dropdown menus. The table's length is variable based on user inputs, and after a certain height, the table begins to scroll.

Presently, the dropdowns will fall over subsequent rows in the table, just like I'd like it to do. However, if I select dropdown components toward the bottom of the table, and the table's parent container is full, then the table's parent container expands so that it is large enough to fully enclose the dropdown menu, and the user has to scroll down to see the dropdown menu. I would like to figure out how to set this up so that the dropdown menu appears outside of the parent div, without causing it to expand at all.

I imported an editable version of the React-Responsive-Select component's CSS sheet so that I could modify it as needed, but so far the only changes have been to background colors for the dropdown components. I've tried setting the z-index of the dropdown menu to an absurdly large value and the parent div's z-index to 0, but that hasn't worked for me. My best guess is that I'm not understanding something about how z-indexes are inherited.

Unfortunately, my coding machine isn't allowed on the Internet, so I can't post code, but I can give you my [artist's rendering of][2] what's happening and what I'd like to have happen.

Edit: To be a bit more compliant with showing code, right now I have a dropdown item, a dropdown container, and a scrolling container.

The dropdown container and the scrolling container are both positioned relative, while the dropdown item is positioned absolutely.

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-select
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHJZV.jpg

Comment: *Unfortunately my coding machine isn't allowed on the Internet, so I can't post code* unfortunately that means your question is off topic for SO until you are able to post your code

Comment: Make sure your parents element doesn't have `overflow: hidden;`